# When I open a new tab using JS, some browser history is kept. How to remove it?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm developing a web application and the users can access the system using both Firefox and Chrome. There are some menus that, when the users selects an option a new tab opens, displaying the desired page. The new page is opened using JavaScript: `window.open(<desiredPage>, '_blank')`.

In Chrome the new tab has no history, meaning the user cannot go back using the browser's backward button. In Firefox, in the exact moment the tab opens, there are pages in the history, meaning that the user could go back. How to prevent this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best way to get your question answered is to include a re-producible code example.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will prevent use of the back button:

```
var yourWindow = window.open();
yourWindow.opener = null;
yourWindow.location = "https://www.google.com";
yourWindow.target = "_blank";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not my intention to open a new window, but a new tab.

Comment: Oh my bad. I edited my answer with a new tab as opposed to a new window.

Comment: Still doesn't solves my problem... I think it might be a firefox issue, because the problem doesn't happen when using chrome...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { target: '_blank', href: 'your_url'}).click();
```

It will create an `object` with `your_url` as `href`, and `click` it to open a new tab.

Comment: According to [Firefox Web Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), `window.location.replace` reloads the current page. I need to open a new tab, not reload the current page.

Comment: (After #1 edit) I replaced my `window` call with the code you put in your answer, but it doesn't even change the page. The problem, as I meant, is most likely in the difference between firefox and chrome, not in JS

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(product.page, '_blank', "noreferrer")
```

Comment: Hi! Please consider adding a explanation to your code so OP and future readers can benefit more